# Count other prices from price incl tax

Tags: woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

we need to solve problem with prices and taxes based on country:
In EU countries we need 21% tax. For non-EU countries we need 0% tax.

**We need to have always price $89 incl. Tax.**

When I set up in Woocommerce Price incl. tax and put there $89 - it's counting that this is the price incl. tax, but realculating price:
**For 0 % VAT**
from 21 % as **$89 - 0.21*$89 = price for non EU countries**.

We need:

**Price for EU:**

$ 89 % incl tax, 21% tax, $73,6 without Tax

**Price for non EU:**

$ 89 % incl tax, 0% tax, $0 without Tax

Any ideas how to manage this?

Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 0):

There are plugins available, I have used [Aelia Price by Country](https://aelia.co/shop/prices-by-country-woocommerce/) in the past.

There is also this, experimental, official option:

> A common feature request is to charge the same amount everywhere and
>   absorb the differences in taxes. To enable this feature in 2.5 you
>   would use the code:

```
 add_filter( 'woocommerce_adjust_non_base_location_prices', '__return_false' )
```

More Details [here](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/How-Taxes-Work-in-WooCommerce#prices-including-tax---experimental-behavior).